# Executing script on a precise tab in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want to execute a script on a precise tab of my browser. This script will give back a value.

I don't know what I have to use. The Doc says that `contentScript` are called on every loading of a new page. I just want to execute the script once the user clicked on a button in my popup.html.

Answer (score 0):

In your contentScript file add listener like this:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
   //do job 
   sendResponse(...);
});
```

And in your `popup.html` on click event:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabid, "message", function responseCallback(response) {
   //...
});
```

more info http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage